# webscrape data python beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to receive a quote(price) for STOXX Europe 600
I used a way which succeed for few of the parameters but no for this parameter 
this is my code :

```
    import bs4
    import requests
    s600=url="https://tradingeconomics.com/israel/stock-market"
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

    S600=soup.find_all('tr',{"data-symbol":"STOXX:IND"})

    print(S600)
```

result -I received an empty list
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One your same line of thought:

```
import bs4
import urllib.request

url="https://tradingeconomics.com/stocks"
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

S600=soup.find('tr',{"data-symbol":"STOXX:IND"})
temp = S600.find('td', {"id":"p"})

print (temp.text.strip())
```

You can change the `data-symbol` parameter to get price for different indices.

Prints:

```
375.32
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL for STOXX Europe 600 is `https://tradingeconomics.com/stoxx:ind`.

Then:

```
import bs4
import requests

url="https://tradingeconomics.com/stoxx:ind"
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('#market_last').text)
```

Prints:

```
375.32
```